# Variable will not be inferred because it is bound to a field in an enclosing scope?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, crystal-reports, vb6

I'm rewriting a VB6 app to VB.net, and have come across this error:

`The type for variable "crxTable" will not be inferred because it is bound to a field in an enclosing scope.`

I have this code:

```
Private crxTable as CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable

For Each crxTable in crRep.Database.Tables
   'do stuff
Next
```

From what I understand, the error occurs because `crxTable` is essentially used twice, which leads me to ask:

What is the better approach? To use a different name in the `For Each`, such as `table`, or to use the fully qualified name - `Me.crxTable / MyBase.crxTable`? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Usually, class variable start with an underscore in .NET. This would fix your problem. Private _crxTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use a different name to avoid [this warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385162.aspx) and to avoid issues which could arise if someone forgets/doesn't know that the loop in this method modifies the field.

So i would use this:

```
Private CRX_Table As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable

' ..... '

For Each crxTable As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable In crRep.Database.Tables
   'do stuff
Next
```

If you can omit the `As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable` in the `For Each`-loop depends on whether `crRep.Database.Tables` returns a strongly typed collection or not.

Note that you could avoid the warning also by providing the type yourself with `As`:

```
Private crxTable As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable

' ..... '

For Each crxTable As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable In crRep.Database.Tables
   'do stuff
Next
```

Now you dont get a warning but the code is still dangerous.  The value of the field `crxTable` changes on every iteration of the loop. So it stores only the last `CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable` of all tables. I wouldn't use the field in a loop. Period.

Comment: Great stuff, will accept when SO lets me.

If I understand, is `crxTable As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable` the same as using `Me.crxTable`?

Comment: @Tom: i don't understand, `As` tells the compiler which type it is, `Me.CRX_Table` refers to a field in the class. So that are two different things.

Comment: @Tom: note that i've edited my answer to show you that you **could** avoid that warning by providing the type yourself. But don't do it. Instead use two different variables. Actually i think that you don't need the field at all.

Comment: I saw your string of edits, great explanation and exactly what I wanted, especially being a newcomer to VB!